# Does Verizon Prepaid Mobile Broadband work on Android PHONES?

Tags: verizon

According to [this page](http://www.verizonwireless.com/b2c/mobilebroadband/?page=products_prepaidmb):

> Prepaid Mobile Broadband usage is not
>   available on any PC cards. Only
>   available on Express-Cards, USB
>   modems, Intelligent Mobile Hotspots
>   and Mobile Broadband Built-In on
>   **select notebooks/netbooks**.

Note how cell phones are missing from that list. Does this mean that Android **phones** are excluded from Verizon's **Prepaid** Mobile Broadband?

Comment: Update: I found this great [comparison chart](http://www.prepaid-wireless-guide.com/prepaid-wireless-broadband-plans.html), but it is still unclear whether Verizon Prepaid Mobile Broadband work on Android **phones**. Why the ambiguity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, mobile broadband is called such specifically to distinguish it from a cell phone data plan.  You *might* be able to trick them by claiming your phone is one of the tablets they support, but only if you can get all its info (IMEI etc.) beforehand and they accept it, rather than requiring you to bring in the device.

However I believe they are able to detect this sort of trickery on a network level, even if you're not an existing customer and they know that your device is a phone.  I would not expect it to work for long.  I did a similar thing on T-Mobile and my service was cut after 2 days.